# Existence of $n$-lines in a 2 coloring of a $n^{n}$ hypercube

Tags: graph-theory, combinatorial-geometry, discrete-geometry

Take an $n$-dimensional discrete hypercube with side $n$ - i.e., containing $n^{n}$ nodes. Consider all black/white colorings of it. Does such a coloring exist without a full straight line of $n$ identically colored nodes?

As motivation, this can be considered as a multidimensional version of tic-tac-toe or connect four.
The board is this $n \times n \times...n$ cube. Players alternate coloring nodes. Is a draw possible?

For $n=2$ the answer is obviously false. Less obviously, for $n=3$ it seems to also be false. Is it true for 4 and beyond?

---

Edit: to clarify, all diagonals are allowed.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit diagonals **are** allowed, as they are in connect-four and tic tac toe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $n=4$ a draw is possible. A construction is given by Golomb and Hales in the paper Hypercube Tic-Tac-Toe:

[image]

This diagram seems mysterious, so let me unpack.

We think of a $4$-dimensional coordinate $(a,b,c,d)$ as giving a coordinate $(a,b)$ on the first $4\times 4$ board above and a coordinate $(c,d)$ on the second $4 \times 4$ board. We label $(a,b,c,d)$ with a $+$ if the product of the signs on the two boards is positive: both are $+$, or both are $-$. Otherwise, we label $(a,b,c,d)$ with a $-$. The claim is that if $+$ and $-$ are the two players' moves, the position is a draw.

To see this, note that a line in the $4$-dimensional grid is the product of:

- A line in the first board and a line in the second, or
- A line in one board and a point in the other.

The first kind of line does not cause a problem because of the key property: all lines in the first board have an **even number** of $+$'s, and all lines in the second board have an **odd number** of $+$'s. When you multiply two such lines together, the result will have an odd number of $+$'s as well, and so it can't be $+,+,+,+$ or $-,-,-,-$.

The second kind of line does not cause a problem simply because neither $4\times 4$ board has a winning line, and this doesn't change if you multiply the line by a $+$ or a $-$.

---

In fact, we can do better. The same "product" idea works if we start with the two $4\times4\times4$ colorings below, giving us a $6$-dimensional $4\times4\times4\times4\times4\times4$ draw. (It can be checked that the two colorings have the same "even" and "odd" properties respectively.) Instead of $+$ and $-$ I've used red and blue in the diagram below.

[image]

---

For every $n$, there is a dimension in which a draw is impossible, by the [Hales–Jewett theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hales%E2%80%93Jewett_theorem). This theorem shows a stronger statement in two ways: it shows that there is a dimension in which no matter how the grid is colored (not necessarily with equal amounts of each color) there will be not just a line, but a line with nonnegative slope in each coordinate. Upper bounds on the dimension necessary tend to be very large, however.

For $n > 4$, we can get ever-larger, at least exponentially growing, lower bounds on the dimension in which a draw is possible, via the [van der Waerden numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waerden_number). The van der Waerden $W(2,k)$ is the least integer such that we cannot $2$-color $\{1,2,\dots,W(2,k)\}$ without finding a $k$-term arithmetic progression. So there is a coloring of $\{1,2,\dots,W(2,k)-1\}$ without such a progression. We can use it to construct for $d = \frac{W(2,k)-2}{k-1}$ a draw in a $d$-dimensional hypercube with side $n=2k$, as follows:

- Label each cell in the grid with the number of steps it is from a center square. Each step can change only one coordinate at a time. These numbers range from $1$ to $1+(k-1)d = W(2,k)-1$.
- Color each cell according to its numerical label, by the coloring that avoids $k$-term arithmetic progressions.
- In half of the grid (say, the half with first coordinate $k$ or less), flip the coloring: this ensures that an equal number of cells of each color exist.

Then along every line, there will not just be two colors: along every line, if we take either the first or the second half of that line, then labels along that half will form a $k$-term arithmetic progression, so just that half of the line will include two colors.

For $n=2k+1$, we can extend this same coloring by carefully "inserting" some cells at the center.

Comment: Incredible. Thanks!

Comment: can you say what happens beyond 4? Is there a dimension above which a draw is impossible?

Comment: @OfekShilon I've added some information on the general problem.

Comment: I wish I could +10 this.